# Sql query gets too slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Few days ago I wrote one query and it gets executes quickly but now a days it takes 1 hrs.
This query run on my SQL7 server and it takes about 10 seconds.
This query exists on another SQL7 server and until last week it took about
10 seconds.
The configuration of both servers are same. Only the hardware is different.

Now, on the second server this query takes about 30 minutes to extract the s
ame details, but anybody has changed any details.

If I execute this query without Where, it'll show me the details in 7
seconds.
This query still takes about same time if Where is problem

Comment: Show the query you are executing please.

Comment: the query is too long so that i can not post it. but this uses inner joins left outer join and user defined function and join on other database also

Comment: have you updated stats on all tables and indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the query and probably the data I can't do a lot other than offer tips.

1. Can you put more constraints on the query. If you can reduce the amount of data involved then this will speed up the query.
2. Look at the columns used in your joins, where and having clauses and order by. Check that the tables that the columns belong to contain indices for these columns.
3. Do you need to use the user defined function or can it be done another way?
4. Are you using subquerys? If so can these be pulled out into separate views?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how much data is going into your tables, and not knowing your schema, it's hard to give a definitive answer but things to look at:

1. Try running `UPDATE STATS` or `DBCC REINDEX`.
2. Do you have any indexes on the tables? If not, try adding indexes to columns used in `WHERE` clauses and `JOIN` predicates.
3. Avoid cross table `OR` clauses (i.e, where you do `WHERE table1.col1 = @somevalue OR table2.col2 = @someothervalue`). SQL can't use indexes effectively with this construct and you may get better performance by splitting the query into two and `UNION`'ing the results.
4. What do your functions (UDFs) do and how are you using them? It's worth noting that dropping them in the columns part of a query gets expensive as the function is executed per row returned: thus if a function does a select against the database, then you end up running n + 1 queries against the database (where n = number of rows returned in the main select). Try and engineer the function out if possible.
5. Make sure your JOINs are correct -- where you're using a `LEFT JOIN`, revisit the logic and see if it needs to be a LEFT or whether it can be turned into an INNER JOIN. Sometimes people use LEFT JOINs, but when you examine the logic in the rest of the query, it can sometimes be apparent that the LEFT JOIN gives you nothing (because, for example, someone may had added a `WHERE col IS NOT NULL` predicate against the joined table). INNER JOINs can be faster, so it's worth reviewing all of these.

It would be a lot easier to suggest things if we could see the query.